# How to auto expand the textbox horizontally when the text is too long in WPF?

Tags: wpf, textbox

How do I configure the textbox so that it will automatically expand itself when the inputted text is too long (longer than the width of the textbox)?

I don't want to wrap the text to a new line under, but instead, I want to expand the textbox automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give any fixed width to your textbox, it will resize itself per text string length.
Just give columnWidth of your container to be Auto where its placed.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="I don't care about width anymore..!!!"/>
</Grid>
```

This will work as text suggested.

Comment: I would recommend setting a *MinWidth* on the TextBox. With just Auto, the textbox (assuming it doesnt start with text) would only be big enough for the caret and the user might not understand that it is a TextBox.

Answer (score -1):

Very simple solution use built-in wordwrap function.

Comment: This isn't an answer.  The user explicitly stated "I don't want to wrap the text to a new line under."